# android checkbox returns java.lang.nullpointerexception

Tags: android

Hi I have a checbox and want to do something if the check box is checked but I am getting a nullpointerexception error when I check if its checked with an if statement:

```
if (chkChickenBreast.isChecked()){
   \\Do Something;
}
```

I have this in my receiptActivity.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.receipt);

    Double priceChickenBreast = 30.00;

    LinearLayout receiptLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.receiptMainLinearLayout);
    TextView menuChickenBreast = new TextView(this);

    final CheckBox chkChickenBreast = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);


    try{
        if (chkChickenBreast.isChecked()){
            menuChickenBreast.setText("Chicken Breast     Php 30.00");
            receiptLayout.addView(menuChickenBreast);

        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        menuChickenBreast.setText(e.toString());
        receiptLayout.addView(menuChickenBreast);
    }

}
```

}

My order.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#99FF50"
android:gravity="top"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView_Main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow_Menu1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView_MenuTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="@string/order_title"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/menu_one"
                android:checked="false"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView_Menu1"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/menu_one"
                android:src="@drawable/chickenbreast" />

        </TableRow>              

    </TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

and my Receipt.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/receiptMainLinearLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#99FF50"
android:gravity="top"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewReceiptTitle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/receipt_title"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

Comment: Are you sure the error is on this line "if (chkChickenBreast.isChecked()){" ?

Comment: You forgot one `</TableRow>` in the end of your layout file

Comment: Check your xml File, you're missing </TableRow>

Comment: @Sw4Tish thnaks..but error still persists

Comment: @Yume117 wll, if I remove the IF statement, the program works fine, i have also tried to to use Try..Catch and the e.toString() give me the error java.lang.nullpointerexception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be your problem is not in CheckBox

Linear Layout id

```
LinearLayout receiptLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.receiptMainLinearLayout);
```

You are using seperate xml file then use Inflater concept

try this code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Double priceChickenBreast = 30.00;

        LinearLayout receiptLayout=(LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.receipt, null);

        TextView menuChickenBreast = new TextView(this);

        CheckBox chkChickenBreast = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

        if (chkChickenBreast.isChecked()) {
            menuChickenBreast.setText("Chicken Breast     30.00");
            receiptLayout.addView(menuChickenBreast);
        }

    }
```

Comment: in another xml file called order.xml.

Comment: Add id attribute into your layout android:id="@+id/receiptMainLinearLayout"

Comment: then use inflater concept

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the checkbox to some value i.e true or false before you check it in if.
Put this in your xml  inside  android:checked="true".

Comment: i tried to put in `android:checked="false"` but it still give me the error

Comment: can you try to put your if inside this chekbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
 public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
 }
});

Answer (score 0):

```
LinearLayout receiptLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.receiptMainLinearLayout);
```

I don't find the `R.id.receiptMainLinearLayout` in your xml.
So the `null pointer exception` occured
when you call  `receiptLayout.addView(menuChickenBreast);`